# Build asp.net mvc 4.5 website on azure devops

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-devops, msbuild-task

I am new on azure devops and not an expert on builds and I have a problem creating a build of an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project

In my "BuildSolution" task, I have the following MsBuild arguments :

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" 
/p:EnableUpdateable=false 
/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

But at the end of the process, I have a package to deploy with WebDeploy.
Here are the files generated :

[image: build generated files]

I don't want this, I only want one zip file containing my "ready to go website". Package that i will upload by FTP next to my webserver.

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You are not archiving your build outputs to be dropped in the Build Drop Location.

All you need to do is add the archive parameter and you will get an output in the desired format.

You can also try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/zipdirectory-task?view=vs-2019) below-mentioned task, it does the job for you very easy!